# NGINX set-up server-block on existing domain names/sites

Tags: nginx

Good day!

Due intense desire to learn new things, I have tried setting up my very own new server which is in Linux and a hosting using Centos Web Panel at home. After the installation process, I then proceeded with the common installation of the necessary configurations including the WebServer. I chose NGINX because I've read that it is lighter and more scalable than Apache, and can be used as a web server or as a reverse proxy. After that I then proceeded with the creation of my new website with the domain I have. After creating my website, it was only then that I have read about Server Blocks in NGINX ([Site I read](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7)).

My question is how can I implement the Server Block method to my existing website? Or should I simply remove my site and create a new one using the server block method?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I created my website by creating an account in `User Accounts` category on CWP where I declared my domain name and ip address. Then I was given prompted to User Account dashboard(IP:2082).

Uploading of files is through FTP using my ip/username/password/port which is usually located on `/home/user_account/public_html`. But after seeing the tutorials, everything is set to to `/var/www/domain/public_html`

Comment: please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde I haven't started doing the server block coding yet sir. I am not quite sure how to start because from the link that I have attached, the author created a new directory linked to his sample website.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde From the created website, the site is located in a path "/home/my_website" while in the tutorial its path is " /var/www/example2.com". Sorry I am just new to this. My installation is mostly based on tutorials in the net